# Does a child class inherit the magic methods?

Tags: php, oop

if I have a parent class named: **model**

```
class Model{

    __construct(){
        //do something
    }

    __destruct(){
        //do something
    }

}
```

and some child classes like **child1**, **child2** ...

```
class child extends Model {

    // some code

}
```

does child class inherit the *magic methods*(**__destruct**, ... ) from the parent class?

Comment: I don't see why childs will not inherit magic methods of their parents especially if you do not rewrite it in your childs

Comment: You could add an `echo` to the parent methods and then try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does inherit the parents methods until you overload them. But when overloading, you can call them by preceeding `parent::`.

```php
class Model {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump('From Model');
    }
}

class A extends Model {
}

class B extends Model {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump('From B');
    }
}

class C extends Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump('From C');
    }
}

$m = new Model();
$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$c = new C();
```

> Result from **$m = new Model();**
>
> string(10) "From Model"

---

> Result from **$a = new A();**
>
> string(10) "From Model"

---

> Result from **$b = new B();**
>
> string(6) "From B"

---

> Result from **$c = new C();**
>
> string(10) "From Model"
>
> string(6) "From C"

Comment: thank you i was trying with __destruct and it worked too.

Comment: You can do that with any method. This is the big advantage of inheritance.